# Linq Pattern Matching Problem

Tags: c#, linq

The code below searches through a file to see if a pattern matches and stores the file offset in the 'result' variable. I then had a for each loop which cycles through the 'result' variable to display the offsets which worked fine ... Untill, I had some further code to read in the file contents at each offset and perform a calculation on each read in and output it in the console.

For some reason the for each loop is only outputing the first calculation, instead of continuing to do all the other offsets.

Any help to why this for each loop is stopping at the first offset?

Thanks in advance

```
 byte[] pattern = 00 00 00 08 00;
 byte[] file = "C:\\123.cfg";

 var result = Enumerable.Range(0, file.Length - pattern.Length + 1)
                   .Where(i => pattern.Select((b, j) => new { j, b })
                                      .All(p => file[i + p.j] == p.b))
                   .Select(i => i + pattern.Length - 1);


foreach (var value in result) {

    int startaddress1 = value + 1;
    int EndAddress1 = value + 4;

    int startaddress2 = EndAddressLong + 1;
    int EndAddress2 = EndAddressLong + 4;

    MyGlobals.123_filepath = "C:\\123.cfg";

    ///////////////////////////// Read in the selected //////////////

    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(MyGlobals.123_filepath),  
    System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode);

    for (int i = startaddress1; i <= EndAddress2; i++)
    {
        br.BaseStream.Position = i;
        MyGlobals.Hexbytes += br.ReadByte().ToString("X2") + ",";
    }


}
```

Comment: Is it throwing an exception? Is the method running to completion?  You need to determine if the the loop has actually been exited or whether it has hung on something.

Comment: did you step through the method?

Comment: Do you have any sort of test coverage?

Comment: I have just changed my code ^^^ Please see the code above as I have updated the previous code insert...... I know that the pattern search has found 13 hits, the code above returns the first hit, with all the calculations correct but however outputs it 13 times instead of working out the rest of the search hits.

Thanks to all your replies!

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is with `Console.ReadKey()` you will need to press a key in order to continue the `foreach` loop

Comment: I did think this however the console just exited.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one reason possible to why the loop exits after one iteration:

- result has only one value inside

Comment: I have just changed my code ^^^ Please see the code above as I have updated the previous code insert...... I know that the pattern search has found 13 hits, the code above returns the first hit, with all the calculations correct but however outputs it 13 times instead of working out the rest of the search hits. Thanks to all your replies!